# Add dependency on existing AWS lambda function for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, dependencies

I want to update my AWS lambda function that is already deployed to AWS.

The lambda is a nodejs function

It has a javascript, package.json and package-lock.json

There is no code or steps that I can find to help with that is clear steps on AWS docs.

I looked for them but I get how to create a function.

Also to be noted I do not have the original code on git or anything. What I have is in the lambda function.

I also need to install an npm package to the function as part of updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetFunction` get the function details which will give you path of s3 from which you can download the code. More details - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#getFunction-property

For Updating the function code use `UpdateFunctionCode` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionCode-property

For Updating function configuration use `UpdateFunctionConfiguration` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateFunctionConfiguration-property

Comment: how can I add npm package as well to the lambda then any ideas

Comment: when you will download your zip, it will have a package.json. You can insert/update packages using npm instll and reupload the zip using `updateFunctionCode` method

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answer for other people’s reference